# The window where I select 'something else' while installing Ubuntu isn't being shown. Also, it's not reading any partitions on the disk. What to do?

Tags: system-installation

There's no partition being displayed. I don't want to lose windows.  I'm not getting the option of selecting 'something else' so I can assign disk space to Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: 1. Creating unallocated space for Ubuntu is better done directly in Windows, at Disk Management by shrinking the partition, then rebooting to make sure Windows is happy with the changes. 2. The previous point is unrelated to the issue you reported, that has to do with the SATA mode in UEFI that is currently set to other than AHCI. 3. You need to install AHCI drivers in Windows before changing the aforementioned setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What'll installing ahci drivers do?

Comment: It'll allow Windows to work with AHCI. Otherwise it won't boot after changing that setting. And it needs to be AHCI for the Ubuntu installer to recognize the drives.